# Close and go to an activity after user downtime

Tags: android

I want to make a method (service, alarm, etc.) that can be calculated after x downtime user with the app

Which closes the current activity

and will send the initial activity (login)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer

code is

```
private long startTime=15*60*1000; // 15 MINS IDLE TIME
private final long interval = 1 * 1000;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);

}

@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){

    super.onUserInteraction();

    //Reset the timer on user interaction...
    countDownTimer.cancel();            
    countDownTimer.start();
}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
        // CIERRA LA APP MATANDO EL PROCESO Y VUELVE A ABRIRLO. 
         android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-count-down-timer-example.html

new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
   //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
}

public void onFinish() {
    mTextField.setText("done!");
}

}.start();
```

Refer this link and some examples on countdown timer if you want to use this.

Comment: thank you very much, is what I wanted but as I can detect the use of the user with the app or not.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
act.finishAffinity();
act.startActivity(new Intent(act, actMain.class));
```